# How to understand an Index Error Message?

Tags: dataframe, confusion-matrix, index-error

I am attempting to use the [pretty-print confusion-matrix library](https://github.com/wcipriano/pretty-print-confusion-matrix) to create a confusion matrix.

When I run `pp_matrix(df, cmap=cmap)`, I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/name/folder/subfolder/subsubfolder/prepositions.py", line 27, in <module>
    pp_matrix(df, cmap=cmap)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pretty_confusion_matrix/pretty_confusion_matrix.py", line 222, in pp_matrix
    txt_res = configcell_text_and_colors(
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pretty_confusion_matrix/pretty_confusion_matrix.py", line 59, in configcell_text_and_colors
    tot_rig = array_df[col][col]
IndexError: index 37 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 37
```

The first few lines of my DateFrame look like this:

```
               in   auf   mit   zu  ...  an-entlang  auf-entlang  ohne  außerhalb
into          318     8    10    9  ...           0            0     0          0
in           4325   727   681   62  ...           0            0     0          0
on            253  3197   215   46  ...           0            0     0          0
at            206   280    54    9  ...           0            0     0          0
with          384   397  2097   24  ...           0            0     0          0
by             31    12    23    0  ...           0            0     0          0
in-front-of    15    15    25    0  ...           0            0     0          0
```

The total size is 49 rows x 36 columns.

I *think* the issue has to do with zero-indexing in Python, but to be honest, I'm not even sure how to go about debugging this.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you post how you are reading/defining the dataframe?

Comment: Hi @AlessandroCosentino - sorry for the delayed response; I did not see your comment until now. <br/> If I understand your question correctly, I am defining the dataframe as a nested dictionary that I have: `df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(en_de_dict, orient='index')`